# how to initialize muti-dimension C++ std arrays including zero initialization?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, initialization, std, zero-initialization

I have a two dimensional std array such as,
array<array<int, 9>, 9> tbl;

How to initialize it with the same value such as -1?
If I just want it to be zero-initialized, what is the best way to it?

Comment: *what is the best way* -- There is no "best way".  There may be good ways, bad ways, or depends on use.  By wording your question with "best way", the question now becomes opinion-based.

Comment: Thanks. Opinion based is ok as it might pertain to different use cases.

Answer (score 0):

As @PaulMcKenzie has stated, there isn't a single best way to do something.

For zero initializing the entire array, you can probably use aggregate initialization method.

```c++
std::array<std::array<int, N>, N> arr{0};
```

This method only works for zero-initialization of the array.

But if you want to initialize the array with a custom number throughout, you would need to iterate through all the elements and assign them manually.

```c++
std::array<std::array<int, N>, N> arr;

for(auto& row : arr)
  for(auto& i : row)
    i = -1;
```

Comment: Thanks. Another potential solution that I am thinking is to memset the row data of the array.

Comment: `memset` is a concept of C. If you are trying to do it in C++, then use the functions in the STL like `std::fill`  present in `<algorithm>` header, or you could try using `std::valarray` if you are applying many numerical computation on the elements.